# как узнать цвет в формате 0xRRGGBB?

Tags: python

Например у меня есть цвет в формате rgb (255,0,0), как конвертировать/узнать его в формате 0xRRGGBB

Comment: Берёте каждое из 3-х числе, переводите в шестнадцатеричный формат, и склеиваете в одну строку. (255,0,0) = 0xFF0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
color = '0x' + ''.join(f'{x:02X}' for x in (255,0,0))
print(color)
# 0xFF0000
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз вопрос про python, можно использовать `%` для форматирования

```
>>> '0x%02x%02x%02x' % (255, 0, 0)
'0#ff0000'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380726/converting-an-rgb-color-tuple-to-a-hexidecimal-string